# Best Visual Git tool for Mac OSX?

Tags: macos, git-svn

At work we're using SVN as the central repository and I've been using git svn to update/commit my work.

Now that I'm comfortable with using Git on the command line I'm looking for a good visual Git tool that has good support for SVN.

There are quite a few Git tools but none really talk about SVN support so I'm looking to the community here for their experience?

Comment: SVN support in Git tool? Wouldn't anything that works with Git work with Git-svn cloned repo?

Comment: Not necessarily. I installed Tower, added my local Git repo to it and it warned that Git Svn was not fully supported! I haven't found what is or isn't supported yet.

Comment: well that seems strange. I wonder what is the reason for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SourceTree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) is the best I've seen. It also supports [SVN](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/2010/12/14/sourcetree-1-1-released/) integration.

I've also used [Tower](http://www.git-tower.com/) but SourceTree is better in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I thought I would trial Tower first since it's the one you least preferred :P I got a warning with I added my repository that the tool didn't fully support git svn so we'll see how this goes.

Comment: Having evaluated the trials for both I've found SourceTree to be the better one. Thanks.

Comment: @C0deAttack Glad to see you came to the same conclusion.